# Javascript/DOM not detecting new HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm working on a private Chrome extension that injects some code into specific websites. I am successful for all except THIS 1 website (which I cant provide you with login access, sorry).

My extension doesn't detect the new(most) of the html content being loaded on the page after navigating through the site only.

For example, when I run `document.documentElement.innerHTML;` the return string is only the barebones of the page.

The site is using JQuery and I do have JQuery also loaded in my extension, but it still doesn't want to read any elements. **The elements do show up in Developer Console but NOT on the Source Page or Frame's Source Page**

I really need access to those Elements but I can't figure it out.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

**EDIT:** Turns out nothing was working because all the new content was being loaded into an iFrame. Now I have to research iframes :(

This is what the code in the developer's tools looks like

```
<html>
 <iframe src="..." >
  #document
  <html>
   <div id="im trying to get">this content</div>
  </html>
 </iframe>
</html>
```

Comment: more code....less talk.

Comment: It’s possible that the elements you are trying to access are not available because the dom is not ready yet.  Are you waiting for the document ready event?  You could try this: `$(document).ready(function(){console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML;})`

Comment: To see the source of runtime generated HTML you use the developer tools, the page source (Ctrl-U) will never show it. But you say you can see the generated source in the developer tools, so what is the real problem?